# Getting error trying to extract data from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, zapier

I this JSON as `input_data`:

```
{"product":["1\/4 Page Ad (Amount: 25.00 USD, Quantity: 1)"],"currency":"USD","total":"25.00","transactionID":"34444622CG671084E","transactionFee":"1.03","transactionFeeCurrency":null,"payerName":"Laurence J Lafleur","payerEmail":"lafleur.julien@gmail.com","fullname":"Laurence J Lafleur","email":"lafleur.julien@gmail.com","transactionid":"34444622CG671084E","shiptoname":"Laurence J Lafleur","addr":"8 East Street ","city":"NATICK","state":"MA","postal":"01760","country":"US"}
```

And I am trying to extract the information from the `product` field: `1/4 Page Ad (Amount: 25.00 USD, Quantity: 1)`

My code looks like this:

```
var myvar = JSON.parse(input_data)
var myret = myvar.product
return myret
```

I get the following error: `"SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1"`

I would be grateful for pointers, general missing concepts, etc.

With gratitude,

Julien

Comment: looks like its already an object. have you tried just `var myret = input_data.product;
return myret` ?

Comment: I don't think you need to call `JSON.parse()`, as the data is already an object.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's two things wrong.

- Starting with the `SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`:
  You're getting this because you're not using `JSON.parse` on a `string`, you're using `JSON.parse` on an `object`; under the hood, `JSON.parse` will attempt to create a string out of the input you give it if the input is not a string, so `{}.toString() === '[object Object]'`, you're basically running `JSON.parse('[object Object]')` which is not valid JSON (just look at the second character or the character at position 1, it's an 'o' and not a string, a boolean, an object, array or a number)
- The second problem is that `myvar.product` is an array, you're expecting to get what's *inside* the array, not the array itself. You need to return `myvar.product[0]`

Try this:

```js
function test(){
    var data = '{"product":["1\/4 Page Ad (Amount: 25.00 USD, Quantity: 1)"],"currency":"USD","total":"25.00","transactionID":"34444622CG671084E","transactionFee":"1.03","transactionFeeCurrency":null,"payerName":"Laurence J Lafleur","payerEmail":"lafleur.julien@gmail.com","fullname":"Laurence J Lafleur","email":"lafleur.julien@gmail.com","transactionid":"34444622CG671084E","shiptoname":"Laurence J Lafleur","addr":"8 East Street ","city":"NATICK","state":"MA","postal":"01760","country":"US"}'

    var myvar = JSON.parse(data);
    var myret = myvar.product[0];
    return myret;
}
console.log(test());
```